# Media keys on a mouse not detected

Tags: kubuntu, mouse, media-buttons

I have a mouse with a special media stick (it's basically 5 media buttons in one). Neither showkey nor xev show nothing when I try to use that stick. However, it works perfect on Windows out of the box without any additional software, so I assume it sends some default events, but Kubuntu dosen't see them for some reason. I'm running Kubuntu 22.04, mouse is Emisat GM-14 if that matters. Media keys on a keyboard work like a charm.

Comment: The spec sheet of that mouse mentions "7 programmable buttons". So the Windows driver for that mouse might program them with some predefined key syms. You could test that by booting first Windows where you get functions on those buttons and then reboot into Linux. Chances are that in that constellation the buttons keep whatever was programmed onto them.

Comment: @HuHa those buttons work without any Windows software right out of the box, that's why i think they send some default events. I have also tried remapping them in Windows, no effect for Linux.

Comment: If you see "mouse button #x press" events in `xev`, that might be the case. If you don't even see that, you are out of luck. If you see them, it's a matter of assigning key syms to those buttons; `xdotool` might work.

Comment: @HuHa your first comment actually did the trick, did't take in account this mouse has two modes of those buttons. Still can't see those as "button #x", but I've remapped them to Ctrl+Alt+Arrows and then could use them as shortcuts. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the future generations, I will leave the answer here.

With this particular mouse (and with many others I believe), you can bind additional buttons to any key combination, like Ctrl+Alt+Arrow button, with a Windows software, and then use those as custom shortcuts for the media in Ubuntu.